# HTML different button styles - like a gear

Tags: html, angular, electron

I have a button called "setting", and I want this button to look like a gear.
I found this: https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/symbols/gear/
And this: https://www.w3schools.com/icons/tryit.asp?filename=tryicons_fa-gear

But they dont work on my angular/electron project.

This is the current button (a normal one):

```
<button class="flex-buttons"  class="form-control settings">Settings</button>
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">` in the `index.html` to be able to use font-awesome classes like 'fa fa-gear' like in your second example.

Answer (score 1):

Google itself providing the list of icons, try to use this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
</head>
<body>

<i class="material-icons">settings</i>
<i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px;">settings</i>
<i class="material-icons" style="font-size:40px;color:red;">settings</i>
<i class="material-icons" style="font-size:60px;color:green;">settings</i>

</body>
</html>
```